# Extract arguments of method calls with Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, .net, mono, mono.cecil

I am trying to extract all arguments passed to a specific method with Mono.Cecil.
In a post-processing script that runs right after the project being build, I am able to find all method calls, and even extract the type of the argument passed to the function. However, I am not able to get the actual value... So is this even possible with Mono.Cecil, and if yes, what value do I need to look at?

Here is my current code :

```
List<MethodDefinition> methods = new List<MethodDefinition> ();
foreach (ModuleDefinition _module in assembly.Modules) {
    foreach (TypeDefinition _type in _module.Types) {
        methods.AddRange (_type.Methods);
    }
}
var uiExtensionMethod = methods
      .Where(m => m.DeclaringType.Name == "SetCustomText").FirstOrDefault();
var instructions = uiExtensionMethod.Body.Instructions;
var count = instructions.Count;
var instructionArray = instructions.ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (instructionArray [i] != null) {
        if (instructionArray [i].Operand != null) {
            var paramType = instructionArray [i].Operand.ToString ();
            // So here I have the type of the parameter, but I cannot get the value...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with value? `Console.WriteLine("Hello")`, `"Hello"` would be the value? But often it is calculated... `string temp = "HELLO".ToLower(); Console.WriteLine(temp)`... In the not-easiest case you are trying to solve a nearly impossible problem.

Comment: With Mono.Cecil you are looking at a dll, not at a running program... It is like trying to comprehend what a person is thinking by dissecting its dead body....

Comment: I am totally aware of this. I only need to direct calls of the method, exactly like your example with "Hello". I do know I am looking at a dll come on....

Comment: If you only want to redirect the call, then you don't need to know the value of arguments... The arguments are already in the right place... You only need to change the `call`...

Comment: In IL language [see example](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/f:>ilr/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUAB2ACMAbMAYxnJIEMQQYBhGAbzxg5kNIpgDcA9mAAmMALIAKAJSt2neYwEQQAkqgB0AdQBOYNABlIqCQCIAEqhIkBJqTlzyAvnkdA==) you don't write `Console.WriteLine("Hello")`, you write `Load "Hello", Call Console.WriteLine`

Comment: But as stated in my original quesiton, I do not want to redirect the call. I want to get the value of the arguments and process them otherwise...

Comment: But unless you have the simplest case for this reason you can't. It is difficult to associate the `Load` with the `Call`, because the `Load`  works on a stack (it is a `Push`), and the `Call` simply `Pop`s the right number of elements from the stack.

Comment: But for the simplest case, namely `Console.WriteLine("Hello")` , shouldn't it be possible to extract `"Hello"` ?

Comment: I don't say it isnt feasible, decompilers do it, when they work (but they cheat: they know the pattern produced by the originale language)... But it is complex: for example look at [this example](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/f:>ilr/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUAB2ACMAbMAYxnJIEMQQYBhGAbzxg5kNIpgDcA9mAAmMALIAKAJSt2neYwEQQAkqgB0AdQBOYNABlIqCQCIAEqhIkBJmAGoYJgB4n1AFQEBVfPlTbpUji48gC+eCFAA=)... See how a simple expression is made more complex?

Comment: Yes... In that case it is. The technique is, from the Call, look backward and reconstruct the stack. Clearly the last instruction that push something (and isn't popped) is pushing the last parameter. So for each IL instruction you have to know how much it is Pushing and how much it is Popping (probably the Mono.Cecil can help you there)

Comment: Yeah it looks more complex, but still I can see `IL_0000: ldstr "Hello"    
        IL_0005: ldstr "x"  ` so the text is there. The method I want to look at only has one argument and it has to be a string, so why cant I get the value with cecil ?

Comment: Have you looked at the code? The call will get a `HelloX`, because there is a string concatenation and a ToUpper somewhere... And note that the `"Hello"` is in the first line, but it will be used only in the call in the fourth line...

Comment: I am not sure we are talking into the same direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution to this.

The problem was, that Mono.Cecil did indeed find my method calls, but it processed them inside the file, where the argument was already written into a variable, and therefor unable to be converted to a string.

So my solution is, parsing ALL methods that have a string as an Operand, and then detecting their NEXT operation. If the next operation is my function of choice, THEN I found the string I am looking for :)